# Telnet and C Server: Uncleared stream

Tags: c, server, stream, telnet

I create a valid connection, two valid FILEs tx (transmitting) and rx (receiving) and try to receive date sent by telnet and send data to telnet. 
This is the critical code section:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            fprintf(tx, "Send me a message\n");
            while(1){
                c = fgetc(rx);
                fputc(c, stdout);
                if(c == '\n')
                    break;
            }
            fprintf(tx, "Thank you! \n");
}
```

(For whole code, see below)

Now, I start this server and connect to it via telnet, send some text. This is the result:

```
ocean@oogway:~/cTest/Server$ telnet ::1 2017
Trying ::1...
Connected to ::1.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello
how are you
nice to meet you
Send me a message
Thank you! 
Send me a message
Thank you! 
Send me a message
Thank you! 
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

But, looking at my code, I would have had expected to see:

```
Send a message
Hello
Thank you!
Send a message
How are you
Thank you!
...
```

Why does telnet print the date out only when the server terminates?

Complete Code:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static const int LISTEN_PORT = 2017;


static void die(const char *msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main (void){
    int sockfd, flag;
    flag = 1;
    struct sockaddr_in6 host_addr;

    sockfd = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd == -1)
        die("socket");

    host_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    host_addr.sin6_port = htons(2017);
    host_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;

    if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &flag, sizeof(int))
    == -1)
        die("setsockopt");

    if(bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&host_addr, 
        sizeof(host_addr)) ==  -1)
        die("bind");
    if(listen(sockfd, SOMAXCONN) == -1)
        die("listen");

    while(1){
        int client = accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL);

        if(client == -1)
            die("accept");

        int client2 = dup(client);

        if(client2 == -1)
            die("dup");
        FILE *tx;
        FILE *rx;

        tx = fdopen(client, "w");
        rx = fdopen(client2, "r");

        if(!tx || !rx)
            die("fdopen");
        int c;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            fprintf(tx, "Send me a message\n");
            while(1){
                c = fgetc(rx);
                fputc(c, stdout);
                if(c == '\n')
                    break;
            }
            fprintf(tx, "Thank you! \n");
        }
        break;
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Also if someone could improve the title of my question I think others who have this problem wouldnt find it so easily

Comment: just a guess, maybe you have to flush the tx stream with fflush(tx); after your fprintf()

Comment: Yes thats what I thought, too thats why I named the Question the way I did. But I have no idea what fflush( ) actually does and how to use it..

Comment: @Josch Kraus, File streams are buffered, so without flushing you have no direct control when your data is actually written to the file, or socket in your case. What probably happens is the following: You write to your file stream, your data is buffered and when your program terminates filestreams and sockets are automatically flushed. You can test this by calling fclose() on your filestreams before terminating, just put a getchar() before the fclose().

Comment: Solved it. Do you have any source where I can learn more on which I/O mechanisms are buffered and which ones will directly transfer to files / streams ?